# Change Trade Manager software language

Tags: windows, ocr, chinese

I have installed Alibaba Trade Manager [software](http://trademanager.alibaba.com/). Unfortunately it in Chinese language. How to make its interface English? This is its settings window:

[image]

Comment: Unless the software has a language pack, which you didn't state if it does or not, then it won't be possible.  The language of the interface program has, actually more specifically the interface itself, is entirely controlled by the program's author.

Comment: a quick search gives this : http://service.alibaba.com/buyer/faq_detail/13857040.htm